# Npm install error though having correct package.json

Tags: npm, installation, package.json

I m trying todo npm install on windows machine. 
I m getting following error

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ‘...l”: “paul@oshannessy’

Comment: What are the contents of `npm-debug.log`? What are the contents of `package.json`? Is there a `package-lock.json` as well?

Comment: Debug log - I could see Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ‘...l”: “paul@oshannessy’

Comment: The debug log has usually hundreds of lines, not one... Please post all of them. Without context, this error is as meaningless to us as it is to you.